# Discord OAuth2 authentication on Ionic/Capacitor app

Tags: android, ionic-framework, oauth-2.0, discord, capacitor

I am trying to write a web app/android app using Ionic and Capacitor that allows the user to log in using discord. To do so, I am using the Discord API to get a code and then use the code to obtain a token.
While this works fine on the web part, I have a problem on the android part, as the authentication flows needs to open a browser window to allow the user to confirm and then redirect to the application with the code.
To do so I am using the byteowls capacitor oauth2 plugin (https://github.com/moberwasserlechner/capacitor-oauth2). However, after the user opens the browser window, he is not redirected to the app.
To handle the redirection, I set up a deep link on a server I own with a domain. To do so, I just use nginx to provide the .well-known/assetlinks.json. (https://app.ilregnodiwagham.it/.well-known/assetlinks.json).
However, this link does not redirect the user automatically on the app. (Using google chrome it doesn't redirect, using another browser - DuckDuckGo, it displays a prompt to allow the user to go to the app, but only if I visit the URL without the https:// part).
What can I do to correctly set up the Deep Link? Are there alternatives to complete the authentication flow on the android part?

EDIT: If I use the adb shell to check if the domain is verified, I get the legacy_error state:
`com.ilregnodiwagham.companion: ID: 1dfe63ca-a8ba-40f7-8031-78627d101884   Signatures:   [67:BB:5E:48:0A:00:80:39:75:87:4E:7C:E4:B9:CC:8C:F8:F0:7D:87:B5:56:F9:6F:ED:C0:B5:1E:E2:78:C9:4C] Domain verification state:   app.ilregnodiwagham.it: legacy_failure   User 0:   Verification link handling allowed: true   Selection state:   Disabled:   app.ilregnodiwagham.it`

Comment: Hey, were you ever able to solve this?

Comment: @Lothar I found a workaround: I open the discord auth URL in the inApp Browser and, on the redirect, I get the parameter from the url and close the browser.
You can see the code here: https://github.com/ilregnodiwagham/wagham-app/blob/main/src/app/tabs/home/home.page.ts (line 59, discordAuth function)